# I need to know if we can be immortal? In any way ! It could be either biologically or supernaturally

Tags: immortality

Immortality
Ancient Greek immortals
Philosopher's stone
Nicolas flamel
Secret potions
Majic

Comment: We're fairly certain that entropy will get the universe a bit in the future, so that's a limiting factor. Are you looking at intra-universe wormholes for your fictional world? (That's what the site's about). Please take our [tour] and refer to the [help] for guidance as to our ways.

Comment: This looks to be a discussion prompt about the real world, instead of a specific answerable question about building a fictional world. Discussion prompts, overly broad questions, and questions about the real world are all not a good fit for this site.

Comment: I think you need to explain what you mean exactly by immortal :). You can be immortal of age and still die, or you can be immortal and invincible for instance. Also, the question's body or content is the place to explain what you want, not a place to write down the keywords for search engines ^^.

Comment: Well, we already are, so I'm not sure what the basis of the question is. What is the nature of the fictional world you're working on? What is the specific problem you're trying to address?

Answer (score 1):

For a sensible answer, we must first define "immortality". While the ancient Greeks may have just assumed everyone knew what they were talking about, that won't actually suffice for an intelligent discussion of the implications. So let's start off with a few different varieties...

- **Agelessness** - Humans (and most life on Earth) suffer from aging. What we now call "senescence". Even if we live a perfectly healthy life and avoid injury, we will eventually die, and this remains true no matter how many complicating factors we avoid. Staying out of the sun won't do it, calorie restriction won't do it. But if you never age...
- **(Weak) Invulnerability to typical injury** - Humans are weird little wet meat robots, that if you put a few holes in them, they start leaking. Like, a lot. But what if you speared one of them and he didn't leak? If the holes closed up nearly as quickly as you could poke them open?
- **(Strong) invulnerability to injury** - This is more of a supernatural flavor of the above. Whereas the weak form of invulnerability will save you from many sorts of death that plague regular ole immortals, this one is much nicer. Someone tries to vaporize your head with an atomic bomb? Bloop, doesn't really daze you. They spontaneously convert 11% of all the carbon atoms in your body into some radioactive mercury isotope? You just shrug that off. How does it work? How am I supposed to know that, I wasn't born on Mt. Olympus.
- **Supercorporeality** - While you do *seem* to have a meat body like the rest of us, you are composed of something more than mere atomic matter, such that even if all the protons in the universe decay, you'll still be there. There are supernatural variations of this, but also some that are a little more science-fictiony (mind-uploading, escaping the Matrix, etc).
- **Non-biological/non-biogensis origins** - Not only will you not ever die, but you weren't even born... you've always sort of existed. Mostly reserved for deities, gods, and techno-billionaires.

Though I've already touched on some methods, let's talk about a few more.

Various ideas about nanotechnology and nanobots can give you agelessness and weak invulnerability, though supernatural plot points can do the same. Genetic engineering and even just advanced bio-science can maybe do the agelessness thing. Those might even get you started on the (very) weak invulnerability.

Strong invulnerability probably isn't possible with nanotech. While there are some schemes that might allow you to pull off a trick or too once in awhile, nanotech alone won't give you generalized strong invulnerability. For that, you'd need something closer to Star Trek technology... ubiquitous force fields, the ability to put materials back together atom-by-atom, to teleport out of danger when you felt like it.

Supercorporeality is probably the highest form of immortality that pure technology can achieve. You see it alot in science fiction, where people not only do mind-uploading, but they have little indestructible backup devices in their heads, so if they get ganked then a loved one just reboots them in a cloned body. Note: Do not piss off your loved ones, or they might just forget to reboot you.

For the last, it's not necessarily a supernatural-only explanation, but it's definitely either "you have it, or you don't have it and there's no way to get it". Maybe still useful in your story, but not very interesting in my opinion.